# meaning of the word "one" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from [Crash Course US history](https://youtu.be/_3Ox6vGteek). It at 1 minute and 12 second. Here is the context:

> Now, both parties realized that it was important to coordinate their electoral strategy to make sure the vice presedential candidate got at least **one** fewer electoral votes than the presidential candidate.

Would it mean the same if the host said ...*candidate got at least one electoral vote fewer than*...? What confuses me is the use of the word *vote* in its plural form.

Comment: Maybe this article helps you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fewer_vs._less

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have ten dollars and give two of them away, you have  **two fewer dollars** or **two dollars fewer** than you had before.

If you give only one of them away, you have **one fewer dollars** or **one dollar fewer** than you had before.

Comment: If someone gave a dollar, would it be correct to say "now I have one dollar more than him"?

Comment: If you are given a dollar, you now have **one dollar more** than you had previously. The person who gave it to you has **one dollar less** than he or she had previously but still may have more money than you do, so you might not have "one dollar more than him".

Comment: @Dmytro O'Hope  And if you were asking about the objective case **him** (and not trying to trick me with a money question) then you should know that nominative **he** would be hyper-correct.  Overwhelmingly native speakers use **him** there (*...more than him*), although you might find some prescriptive grammars saying that **him** is incorrect and that it should be *more than **he** (has)*.

Comment: I am a bit confused. After a supposed guy give me a dollar he now has one dollar less or fewer? I thought "less" is used for uncountable nouns. Or I am wrong.

Comment: @Dmytro O'Hope  **fewer** is used with countable nouns.  *There were fewer people in the audience tonight than last night*  and **less** is used with amounts. *He would like less porridge*. But **dollars** can be understood either way, as an amount (*I have one dollar less in the bank after buying that candy bar*) or as the countable piece of paper currency (*I have one fewer dollars in my wallet after giving one to Dmytro so he could buy a candy bar*).  But few native speakers would use **fewer** there; most would say *I have one less dollar in my wallet.*

Answer (score 0):

**One fewer** here is a relative amount of *countable* things (= *how many* relatively to some other number), *votes* here. Here's a page with glossary from the book: One More, One Less by April Barth (see 'one less having an amount that is **one fewer**'):

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=cQ38yreHExAC&pg=PA16&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U1ZwJB5HGklUSIq6aLay8IcnpCcQw&w=1280